# Pointers and arrays in Python ctypes

Tags: python, arrays, pointers, ctypes

I have a DLL containing a C function with a prototype like this:

`int c_read_block(uint32 addr, uint32 *buf, uint32 num);`

I want to call it from Python using ctypes. The function expects a pointer to a chunk of memory, into which it will write the results. I don't know how to construct and pass such a chunk of memory. The ctypes documentation isn't much help.

Constructing an array and passing it "byref", like this:

```
    cresult = (c_ulong * num)()
    err = self.c_read_block(addr, byref(cresult), num)
```

Gives this error message:

`ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected LP_c_ulong instance instead of pointer to c_ulong_Array_2`

I guess that is because the Python ulong array is nothing like a c uint32 array. Should I use `create_char_string`. If so, how do I persuade Python to "cast" that buffer to an LP_c_ulong?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can cast with the [`cast`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#type-conversions) function :)

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> x = (ctypes.c_ulong*5)()
>>> x
<__main__.c_ulong_Array_5 object at 0x00C2DB20>
>>> ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong))
<__main__.LP_c_ulong object at 0x0119FD00>
>>>
```

Comment: I've used `ctypes` a few times and I've encountered it in the linked documentation before.

Comment: Why i it a `LP_c_ulong` object and not `LP_c_ulong_Array_5` object

Comment: ``LP_c_ulong_Array_5`` would be an address pointing to an address pointing to the first element in an array of ``uint32``s, whereas the OP's function is looking to receive an address pointing to the first element of an array. ``LP_c_ulong_Array_5`` would be for a function like: ``int c_read_block(uint32 addr, uint32 *buf[], uint32 num);``

Answer (score 4):

You can cast the result, but `ctypes` allows you to use an array in place of a pointer, directly. The issue is the `byref` in your code (which would be the equivalent of a pointer to a pointer):

So instead of:

```
cresult = (c_ulong * num)()
err = self.c_read_block(addr, byref(cresult), num)
```

try:

```
cresult = (c_ulong * num)()
err = self.c_read_block(addr, cresult, num)
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a typo in the solution. In order to get a pointer to an array of ulongs you need to cast to a `POINTER(list of ulong)`

```
In [33]: ptr = ctypes.cast(x, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong*5))
In [34]: ptr
Out[34]: <__main__.LP_c_ulong_Array_5 at 0x23e2560>
```