# How to use OpenGL's glMapBuffer in Python?

Tags: python, opengl, ctypes, memcpy, pyopengl

I want to try updating a VBO in PyOpenGL using `glMapBuffer`, which returns a `ctypes` pointer to the mapped memory. Now, almost all the examples for this function are in C and use `memcpy`, which does apparently not exist in Python as such.

So, how can I update the data using this pointer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointers and arrays in Python ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363163/pointers-and-arrays-in-python-ctypes)

Comment: @vallentin Not really, since I have virtually no experience with `ctypes` , and I understand neither the question nor the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `from_address` from the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to get a ctypes type instance using the memory returned by [`glMapBuffer`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glMapBuffer.html).

The following example maps the buffer to an array of `numberOfFloats` floats:

```py
map_data = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY)
map_array = (GLfloat * numberOfFloats).from_address(map_data)

// copy new data
// [...]

glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER)
```

The elements of `map_array` can be accessed by subscription:

```py
map_array[i] = value
```

Data can be copied form one `ctypes` array to another by `ctypes.memmove(dst, src, count)`.